# C# Sqlite ExecuteReader maximum return

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

What is the maximum amount of rows that can be returned by `ExecuteReader`? I have some 67 rows in a table and it only returns the first 20.

Here's a piece of my source:

```
SQLiteConnection sDBConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Database.ddb;Version=3");
sDBConnection.Open();
string sqlCom = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
SQLiteCommand scdCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sqlCom, sDBConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = scdCommand.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    string Value1 = (string)reader["Col1"];
    bool Value2 = true;
    string Value3 = (string)reader["Col2"];
    object[] row = { Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5 };
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}

reader.Close();
sDBConnection.Close();
```

Of course, the values that aren't in the while loop are defined elsewhere.

Comment: Use the debugger, maybe you have a null value which causes an exception. There is no row-limit for datareaders.

Comment: If there is a maximum it's certainly more than 20.  Something else is wrong. Are there any exceptions?

Comment: No, which is why Im confused. Ive gone through and tested all the values to ensure there are arent any null.

Comment: Do you have value for `Col1` and `Col2` for all rows in the table?

Comment: That did it. Thanks a bunch Jacky. I had a null value in one of the rows but the debugger wasnt throwing any exceptions so I didnt think that was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try edit your code like below :

```
SQLiteConnection sDBConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Database.ddb;Version=3");
sDBConnection.Open();
string sqlCom = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
SQLiteCommand scdCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sqlCom, sDBConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = scdCommand.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
string Value1 = reader["Col1"] != null ? Convert.ToString(reader["Col1"]) : string.Empty;
bool Value2 = true;
string Value3 = reader["Col2"] != null ? Convert.ToString(reader["Col2"]) : string.Empty;
object[] row = { Value1, Value2, Value3 };
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}

reader.Close();
sDBConnection.Close();
```

remove Value4 and  Value5 or give it default value